# A regex to detect things like "[blablablabla]"

Tags: java, regex

I have a text with variables like `[abcderere]`.
In order to detect those variables i decided to create the following regex :

```
(\[.+?\])
```

It does work with string like `[azerty][qwerty]` but I want my regex to also detect String like `[[azerty]` because it matches the pattern but it doesn't work

Comment: Your regex seems to match strings like "[[azerty]" as is. Tested it here: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html and in java itself. Are you using Pattern.compile("(\\[.+?\\])"); ?

Comment: *"My question is pretty simple"*  "What is the meaning of life?" Is also a simple question, it is the answer that is tricky.  The simplicity of a question is unrelated to the simplicity of the answer.  ;)

Comment: In what way exactly does it 'not work'? It will match because `'[[azerty]'` contains `'[azerty]'`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes Pattern.compile In fact only a matching String is detected but in fact 2 matching strings are in [[azerty] : [azerty AND azerty no ?

Comment: To add to that, do you also want it to 'work' with `'[azerty]]'`? Also, why do you want it to work with these seemingly incorrect variable declarations?

Comment: Wait, you mean you want greedy mathcing (match the biggest one and not the smallest one)? Change .+? to .+

Comment: I want to get all the string that match the pattern.  For exemple if I have [[azerty]] , the substring [azerty] is not even detected which is a biggest problem actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help:

```
(\[[^\[\]]+\])
^ ^^     ^  ^^
| ||     |  ||
| |+-----+  ||
| +---------+|
+------------+
```

Given a string such as `[[azerty]`, it will skip the first square bracket and match `[azerty]`. For the string `[[azerty][foobar]]` it will match `[azerty]` and `[foobar]`. [Demo here](http://regexr.com?30or0).

Comment: So for `[[foobar]]` you want it to return both `[foobar]` AND `foobar` to you?

Comment: yep that's exactly what i want ;)  EDIT : for the previous example [[azerty][foobar]] it gives me [azerty] (good) but [[foobar]  :/

Comment: @RomainG: about matching matching brackets, AFAIK it is not possible. Read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets

Comment: I've revised my answer to omit the stray `[`.